# Having trouble updgraring mysql (Obsoleted By: Percona ... )

Tags: mysql, yum, percona

I'm trying to upgrage mysql 5.1 to 5.5.

Following this link step by step : https://www.zerostopbits.com/how-to-upgrade-mysql-5-1-to-mysql-5-5-on-centos-6-7/

But `yum -y update mysql*` gives me errorrs.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                                | 6.9 kB     00:00
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * remi: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
base                                                                                                                                                                         | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00
percona-release-noarch                                                                                                                                                       | 2.9 kB     00:00
percona-release-x86_64                                                                                                                                                       | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi                                                                                                                                                                         | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi/primary_db                                                                                                                                                              | 2.0 MB     00:01
remi-safe                                                                                                                                                                    | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-safe/primary_db                                                                                                                                                         | 941 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.4 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-Server-shared-51.x86_64 0:5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6 will be obsoleting
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.el6_8 will be updated
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.el6_8 will be updated
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.el6_8 will be obsoleted
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.el6_8 will be updated
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.el6_8 will be updated
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be an update
remi/filelists_db                                                                                                                                                            | 2.4 MB     00:01
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-devel-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: mysql-devel-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-Server-shared-56.x86_64 0:5.6.39-rel83.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-devel-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.58-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.58-1.el6.remi
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64 (@base)
               Not found
           Obsoleted By: Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 (percona-release-x86_64)
               Not found
           Updated By: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi
Error: Package: mysql-devel-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.58-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.58-1.el6.remi
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64 (@base)
               Not found
           Obsoleted By: Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 (percona-release-x86_64)
               Not found
           Updated By: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.58-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.58-1.el6.remi
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64 (@base)
               Not found
           Obsoleted By: Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 (percona-release-x86_64)
               Not found
           Updated By: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It seems a `Percona and mysql` dependency problem.

But weird thing is, I have removed the whole Percona things.

`yum remove Percona-Server-shared-51-\*` says

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: Percona-Server-shared-51-*
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * remi: mirror.bebout.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.bebout.net
Package(s) Percona-Server-shared-51-* available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Please teach me how to fix it.

Comment: Try disabling the percona repository.

Comment: @RemiCollet `yum-config-manager --disable percona`, `yum-config-manager --disable percona-release-noarch` is it correct? Still the same :(

Comment: Use the name reported in your output: yum-config-manager --disable percona-release-x86_64

Comment: I tried `yum-config-manager --disable Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64` and nothing happends..

Comment: Have you read my previous comment ?

Comment: @RemiCollet My apologies. I thought I have to type the exact name and case. It's finally done! Thanks!